# exp transform on both x and y axis in sjPlot and Effects packages

Tags: r, logging, transform, ngrx-effects, sjplot

I have log transformed an offset in a glmmtmb model, i have also log transformed some covariates within the model.

As a result i need to back-transform in my correlation coefficients but can't seem to achieve the desired effect in sjPlot or the Effects package.

I can't easily provide a workable example, but i'm hoping someone has used a package or technique to allow them to do this.

I'll be honest i don't know tonnes about this as i a masters student and have only done limited r-coding.

I have tried creating correlation coefficients with sjPlot
'plot_model(ESm, type ="eff", terms =c("DISTURB[all]"))' #gives x axis in log
with effects
'plot(effect('poly(DISTURB,2)', ESm))' # gives both axis in log.

In another CC i used ', transformation=list(link=log, inverse=exp)' which log transformed the y axis though the values are still out of line.